# Adding an object with "text"

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nsobject

I'm stumped or just not finding info I need, I have an object that I want to save in an array when they select "saveDataround" button, however I can't seem to figure out how to populate the object with the text "Round": I'm getting an "Expected identifier" and "Expected , ;" errors on the first and second lines of code. Thanks in advance.

```
[NSString *roundChoice = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Round"];
self.round.text = roundChoice;]

- (IBAction)saveDataround {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *recipient = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/arrayChoiceRound", documentsDirectory];
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [array addObject:round.text];
    [array writeToFile:recipient atomically:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are the first two lines of code implemented? What are they supposed to do?

Here's how I would modify the above code without more info:

```
// remove "[" from start of line & no need to use stringWithFormat here
NSString *roundChoice = @"Round";

// remove "]" from end of line
self.round.text = roundChoice;

- (IBAction)saveDataround {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    // use stringByAppendingPathComponent here
    NSString *recipient = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"arrayChoiceRound"];
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // use self here (not required)
    [array addObject:self.round.text];

    [array writeToFile:recipient atomically:NO];

    // release the array
    [array release];
}
```

Comment: +1 for not only fixing syntax errors, but also improving the code.

Comment: Thanks, i'm still getting an error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '.' token

after  self.round.text = roundChoice;

Comment: Well, it depends on what you are trying to do. You definitely can put them inside the saveDataRound method.

Comment: Thanks again...overall I'm having someone select a button that creates a text file that says "round", I'll later pull that out to place in an e-mail. (I have code for that and it's working fine),

I went ahead an put them in the saveDataRound method, The array isn't writing though, when I had a problem like this first go around the array was empty and that why it didn't write. any ideas?

Comment: You can check if the array has objects by using NSLog: NSLog(@"%@",array);

Comment: i can tell if it writes by looking in the Documents Directory I did "build and analyze" and it showed " Method returns an Objective-C object with a +1 retain count (owning reference) connecting the 1st line: NSString and the "NSMutableArray *array.." line.

Comment: That comment is because the code is leaking the array. I have fixed it above. This has nothing to do with any issues you are having in actually writing the file.

Comment: Nice. You rock. I have a weird feeling my button isn't working to  start the -(IBAction), I'm going to rebuild that in case I screwed that up.

Comment: It seems to be wanting to do something now, i have this error in debugger console:'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: attempt to insert nil'

Comment: If you run in debug mode, the debugger should break where the error is occurring. In any case, the error is self explanatory. You are attempting to add a nil object to an array.